# VBA Word: Copy/Paste selection into new list

Tags: excel, vba, list, ms-word, paste

I am quite new to VBA and have managed to get this far with my code. It currently searches my Word document for a string "The_XXXX" (where X is a # 0-9), is able to copy the string, and then finds the next instance. I would like to be able to paste each instance into a list, after it copies Selection.Copy, or even create an Excel sheet with each instance of the string into a new cell. There will be about 100 instances.

```
Sub FindString()

Dim findRange As Word.Range
Set findRange = ActiveDocument.Range

'CREATE LIST HERE

With findRange.Find
    .ClearFormatting
    .Text = "The_[0-9]{4}"
    .MatchWildcards = True

    Do While .Execute(Forward:=True) = True
        findRange.Select
        Selection.Copy
        
        'ADD TO LIST/EXCEL HERE
        
        findRange.Collapse wdCollapseEnd
    Loop
End With

End Sub
```

Comment: Add your found items to a scripting.dictionary or arraylist

Comment: @freeflow - I think he wants someone to do it for him. The code in the question comes from the answer to a [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64068772/word-vba-scan-document-for-string-copy-it-to-list-and-move-to-next-occurrence)

Comment: @TimothyRylatt Not from me.  He's had a pointer.  He should work it out for himself now.

Comment: @TimothyRylatt I added the empty array using Dim Names() As String, but when I tried to add the selection to the array using Names = Selection.Value, it doesn't quite work. Any pointers?

Comment: @freeflow See above comment. Would Names = findRange.Add work?

Comment: @Mike - there is no such thing as `Selection.Value`. Learn to use Intellisense and the Object Browser